# How to pass parameters to this function : void func(int rows, int columns, int matrix[rows][columns])

Tags: c++

The function that I'd like to call is as follows.

```
void func(int rows, int columns, int matrix[rows][columns]) {
    cout << matrix[rows-1][columns-1] << endl;
}
```

The Clion compiler told me that the real type of the matrix is `int(*)[columns]`.
I tried many ways to pass the parameter but all failed when run the `func`. Here are some of my ways of passing parameters.
[image]

[image]

It seems that the length of the array pointed to by the formal parameter `matrix` is a variable. But should't an array pointer should declare the size of columns?
Why the `func` could pass compilation?
If this is reasonable, how to pass parameters to `func`?

Comment: The function template described in the target only takes a 1D array, but it's straightforward to have it take a 2D array instead.

Comment: The function declaration you are showing is valid in C, but not in C++. How to call the function is not the issue. You cannot write a function like that in standard C++ in the first place.